# VB.NET Array Intersection

Tags: vb.net, arrays, intersection

This could be terribly trivial, but I'm having trouble finding an answer that executes in less than n^2 time. Let's say I have two string arrays and I want to know which strings exist in both arrays. How would I do that, efficiently, in VB.NET or *is* there a way to do this other than a double loop?

Comment: What version of .NET?  in 3.5 you could use the linq extension for Intersect

Comment: I believe we are using 2.0 at this point. Corporate hosting policy, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The simple way (assuming no .NET 3.5) is to dump the strings from one array in a hashtable, and then loop through the other array checking against the hashtable. That should be much faster than an n^2 search.

Comment: It was probably best if they were in a hashset, dictionary, or list rather than an array in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you sort both arrays, you can then walk through them each once to find all the matching strings.

Pseudo-code:

```
while(index1 < list1.Length && index2 < list2.Length)
{
   if(list1[index1] == list2[index2])
   {
      // You've found a match
      index1++;
      index2++;
   } else if(list1[index1] < list2[index2]) {
      index1++;
   } else {
      index2++;
   }
}
```

Then you've reduced it to the time it takes to do the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Sort both lists. Then you can know with certainty that if the next entry in list A is 'cobble' and the next entry in list B is 'definite', then 'cobble' is not in list B. Simply advance the pointer/counter on whichever list has the lower ranked result and ascend the rankings.

For example:

List 1: D,B,M,A,I 
List 2: I,A,P,N,D,G

sorted:

List 1: A,B,D,I,M  
List 2: A,D,G,I,N,P

A vs A --> match, store A, advance both 
B vs D --> B
D vs D --> match, store D, advance both 
I vs G --> I>G, advance 2 
I vs I --> match, store I, advance both 
M vs N --> M
List 1 has no more items, quit. 
List of matches is A,D,I

2 list sorts O(n log(n)), plus O(n) comparisons makes this O(n(log(n) + 1)).

Answer (score 2):

If one of the arrays is sorted you can do a binary search on it in the inner loop, this will decrease the time to `O(n log n)`