# C# - Finding the common members of two List<T>s - Lambda Syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

So I wrote this simple console app to aid in my question asking. What is the proper way to use a lambda expression on line 3 of the method to get the common members. Tried a Join() but couldn't figure out the correct syntax. As follow up... is there a non-LINQ way to do this in one line that I missed?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> c = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<int> a = new List<int>() { 5, 3, 2, 4 };
        IEnumerable<int> j = c.Union<int>(a);
        // just show me the Count
        Console.Write(j.ToList<int>().Count.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the lists sorted by specification or is it just your test case that happens to be like that? That would influence a solution. If they're not sorted, you should change your example.

Comment: There is no non-LINQ way to do this in one line. Check out this question for other ways to accomplish this task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674075/vb-net-array-intersection

Comment: Good point. Assume they won't be sorted. Fixing now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want `Intersect()`:

```
IEnumerable<int> j = c.Intersect(a);
```

---

Here's an `OrderedIntersect()` example based on the ideas mentioned in the comments.  If you know your sequences are ordered it should run faster — `O(n)` rather than whatever `.Intersect()` normally is (don't remember off the top of my head).  But if you don't know they are ordered, it likely won't return correct results at all:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderedIntersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> other) where T : IComparable
{
    using (var xe = source.GetEnumerator())
    using (var ye = other.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (xe.MoveNext())
        {
           while (ye.MoveNext() && ye.Current.CompareTo(xe.Current) < 0 )
           {
              // do nothing - all we care here is that we advanced the y enumerator
           }
           if (ye.Current.Equals(xe.Current))
              yield return xe.Current;
           else
           {  // y is now > x, so get x caught up again
              while (xe.MoveNext() && xe.Current.CompareTo(ye.Current) < 0 )
              { } // again: just advance, do do anything

              if (xe.Current.Equals(ye.Current)) yield return xe.Current;
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You made a good point about ordering, though- if they are sorted a Zip -variant would be more efficient

Comment: Yes. Intersect. Couldn't think of the right keyword. +1 and answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you by lambda syntax mean a real LINQ query, it looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> j =
   from cItem in c
   join aitem in a on cItem equals aItem
   select aItem;
```

A lambda expression is when you use the => operator, like in:

```
IEnumerable<int> x = a.Select(y => y > 5);
```

What you have with the Union method really is a non-LINQ way of doing it, but I suppose that you mean a way of doing it without extension methods. There is hardly a one-liner for that. I did something similar using a Dictionary yesterday. You could do like this:

```
Dictaionary<int, bool> match = new Dictaionary<int, bool>();
foreach (int i in c) match.Add(i, false);
foreach (int i in a) {
   if (match.ContainsKey(i)) {
      match[i] = true;
   }
}
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int,bool> pair in match) {
   if (pair.Value) result.Add(pair.Key);
}
```